# Batch proces Colour profiles of images to any profile needed with python

Tags: python, colors, automation

Im working on a project that needs to process images from one file and output to another the change is varied but the main one is colour profiles that need to be changed however everything i see so far is only able to convert to sRGB or that range but i would need to ether be able to add a profile or have an extensive or full list of profiles to convert to. for example one of the profiles ill be needing to use is [eciRGB v2.](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eci.org%2F_media%2Fdownloads%2Ficc_profiles_from_eci%2Fecirgbv20.zip&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHjtbZXTmhkg0SzHW5LVO227XbHaA)
Please help me to automate this in python (I cant use photoshop...) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with ImageMagick and terminal.

Download the colour profile(eciRGB_v2.icc) and make sure you know the path to it, I recommend keeping it in the same directory as your images.
[example set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMw0X.png)

Then open Terminal at that directory and run this code:
convert image.tif -profile eciRGB_V2.icc output.tif
[example of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHdSO.png)

Link to download ImageMagick: https://imagemagick.org/index.php

Comment: Thanks this Helps a lot i was looking into image magic but gave up i just tried it and this works.